# How to think Reactively coming from Promise background (angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, reactivex

How does one think and structure code "reactively", coming from a promise background?

I'm struggling with a very simple setup. I have a method `.authenticate` that should return an observable that yields a boolean (that already makes me fear I'm thinking promishy).

How I'm used to doing things:

```
authenticate() {    
    if(this.userProfile) {  
        return Promise.resolve(true);  
    }  
    if(!this.jwt) {  
        return Promise.resolve(false); // depending on implementation, either reject or resolve with false  
    }  
    return http.post('/exchangetoken')  
        .then(response => {  
            this.user = response.data.profile;  
            this.jwt = response.data.jwt;
            return true;  
        })  
        .catch(error => {
            if(error.status === 400) {
                return Promise.resolve(false)
            }
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });  
}
```

Now in Angular2/TypeScript/ReactiveX I'd like to do the same "reactively"
check `this.userProfile` => if `true` skip the rest and "resolve" `true`
check `this.jwt` => if `false` skip the rest and "resolve" `false`
call some endpoint => if `success` save states and "resolve" `true`, if `false` then "resolve" `false`

Poor attempt so far, I know I'm operators and stuff wrong, but I feel where I'm really going wrong is structuring the process/flow as though I'm building a promise chain:

```
authenticate(nextUrl: string): Observable<boolean> {
    this.redirectUrl = nextUrl;

    if(!!this.userProfile) { return Observable.of(true); }

    if(!this.jwt) { return Observable.of(false); }

    return this.exchangeToken();
  }

exchangeToken(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.oeApi
      .post('v1/auth/exchangetoken')
      .map(response => this.extractProfile(response))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        return Observable.of(false)
      });
  }
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. it does not work?